# What is the backup file created by checkinstall for?

Tags: software-installation, checkinstall

I reinstall emacs by compiling [its source](http://ftp.kaist.ac.kr/gnu/gnu/emacs/emacs-24.5.tar.gz) and then `sudo checkinstall`. I found `checkinstall` creates a file

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 44628516 Apr 22 19:19 emacs_24.5-1_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 56991208 Apr 22 19:19 backup-042220151919-pre-emacs.tgz
```

Does `checkinstall`  create a backup file regardless of which software it installs, or it depends on specific software (e.g. emacs) (maybe depending on the specific Makefile?)?

What is the backup file for?

Shall I keep it, and when can I discard it?

How shall I use it in case it is needed?

Answer (score 4):

When you install package with `checkinstall`, it will automatically make a backup tarball of the currently installed package, if exists (it depends on `./configure --prefix=/dir`). The name is: `backup-<datetime>-pre-<packagename>-<version>.tgz` in directory you are building package. If anything goes wrong with your new package you can roll back to the previous version using:

```
tar -xzvf backup-<datetime>-pre-<packagename>-<version>.tgz -C /
```

It is up to you how long you will keep this backup.

Additional info:

1. When you run `checkinstall` it asks you a couple of question and there is:

   This package will be built according to these values:

   ```
    ...
    3 -  Version: [ x.y.z ]
    ...
   ```

So your backup should be: `backup<datetime>-pre-<packagename>-x.y.z`. Note the word **pre**.

2. If the installed package is installed in `/usr/bin` and your `--prefix=/usr/local/` `checkinstall` will not backup package installed in `/usr/bin`.
3. I think your backup archive is relative to `/`. And

   `tar -xzvf backup-<datetime>-pre-<packagename>-<version>.tgz -C /`

will need `sudo` because it will place files in folders to which ordinary users don't have `write` permission.

Comment: Thanks! (1) Why does my backup file not have `<version>` in its name? (2) does `checkinstall` back up the installed one, only when the installed one exist in the `--prefix=/dir` where the new one will be installed? If the installed one exist in other directory, will `checkinstall` still back it up? (3) when roll back, does `tar -xzvf backup-<datetime>-pre-<packagename>-<version>.tgz -C /
` need `sudo`? Why change to `/` by `-C /`? Isn't my previous `--prefix`, which is generally either `/usr` or `/usr/local`.

Comment: @Tim answer is edited.

Comment: does `tar -xzvf backup-<datetime>-pre-<packagename>-<version>.tgz -C /` need sudo

Comment: It is in the third point.

Comment: the third one is whether `checkinstall` needs sudo. not `tar -xzvf backup-<datetime>-pre-<packagename>-<version>.tgz -C /` need sudo